# Partitioning North America

Tags: python, geo, voronoi

My goal is to create:

[image]

That's a Voronoi Diagram of North America. The problem is that when I run my code, the error informs me `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I don't know why I have this error, and I'm not sure how I can resolve it.

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords

cities = gpd.read_file('world_populated_cities.csv')
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
na = world[world.continent == 'North America']

#cities = cities.geometry.to_crs(epsg=3857)
#na = na.to_crs(epsg=3857)
cities.crs = "EPSG:3857"
na.crs = "EPSG:3857"

na_shape = cascaded_union(na.geometry)
cities = cities.to_crs(na.crs)   # convert city coordinates to same CRS!

cities = cities[cities.geometry.within(na_shape)]

coords = points_to_coords(cities.geometry)
poly_shapes, pts, poly_to_pt_assignments = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, na_shape)

fig, ax = subplot_for_map()
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, na_shape, poly_shapes, coords)
ax.set_title('Cities data for South America from GeoPandas\nand Voronoi regions around them')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('using_geopandas.png')
plt.show()
```

My code can also be found here (Google Colab Notebook): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oDhWsbnrwLAKXpi-f8fhJlsdxhuQrxzw

I'm relatively new to geopandas, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [the docs on Managing Projections: Setting a Projection](https://geopandas.org/projections.html#setting-a-projection).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, I adjusted my code accordingly, setting the cities' crs by doing `cities.crs = "EPSG:3857"`, as per the documentation. While that *has* resolved the crs error, I now have a `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error. Not sure how to proceed;

Comment: Please provide the full trace back for your error.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this, the plot can be generated by setting the correct projection:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords
cities = gpd.read_file('world_populated_cities.csv')
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
na = world[world.continent == 'North America']
cities.crs = ({'init': 'epsg:3857'}) 
cities = cities.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'}) 
na_shape = cascaded_union(na.geometry)
cities = cities[cities.geometry.within(na_shape)]
coords = points_to_coords(cities.geometry)
poly_shapes, pts, poly_to_pt_assignments = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, na_shape)
fig, ax = subplot_for_map()
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, na_shape, poly_shapes, coords)
ax.set_title('Cities data for South America from GeoPandas\nand Voronoi regions around them')
plt.tight_layout()
```

The cities file is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dodge-ttu/687e1087df13a1e00d6506ae13626c53/raw/129c9fedef532a97d8f4989e2d5a927a459bdd08/world_populated_cities.csv).